# Priting all IP addresses from an IP range ssh/bash

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, centos, printf

I am trying to print all IPs from an IP address range such as 72.21.206.0/23 in the command line more preferably with a single command.

I have tried several commands with awk & cut in combination but was not able to achieve the desired result.

For example if I have the following in file3:

```
72.21.110.0/16
72.21.206.0/23
```

and I would like to extract all IPs from 72.21.206.0/23 and print them in separate lines on the screen. I have only reached this point due to my basic knowledge:

```
awk -F'/' 'NR==2{print $1+1}' file3
```

which is supposed to print from my assumptions but it is not:

```
72.21.206.1
```

Could you please help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `nmap` available you can just run something like:

```
nmap -n -sL 72.21.110.0/16
```

This will produce output along the lines of:

```
Nmap scan report for 72.21.0.0
Nmap scan report for 72.21.0.1
Nmap scan report for 72.21.0.2
[...]
Nmap scan report for 72.21.255.253
Nmap scan report for 72.21.255.254
Nmap scan report for 72.21.255.255
Nmap done: 65536 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 33.42 seconds
```

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742839/cidr-converter-using-sed-or-awk) suggest a solution using `ipcalc`.  And having found that, I guess I'm marking this as a duplicate...

**Update**

A solution in `awk`, just for you:

```
BEGIN {
  FS="/"
}

{
  split($1, octets, ".");
  base=lshift(octets[1], 24) + lshift(octets[2], 16)
    + lshift(octets[3], 8) + octets[4];
  max=lshift(1, 32-$2);

  for (i=0; i<max; i++) {
    addr = base + i;
    addr = sprintf("%s.%s.%s.%d", rshift(addr, 24),
          rshift(and(addr, 0x00FF0000), 16),
          rshift(and(addr, 0x0000FF00), 8),
          and(addr, 0xFF))
    print addr
  }
}
```

Given input like this:

```
$ echo 192.168.1.0/28 | awk -f ipranger.awk
```

You get output like this:

```
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
192.168.0.7
192.168.0.8
192.168.0.9
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.13
192.168.0.14
192.168.0.15
```

Comment: The provided solution works only on half the cases since not all servers that I would use the script or command have Nmap. Anyways, thank you for the fast response.

Comment: I've added a pure-`awk` solution.