# AWK supported Regex for ipv4 CIDR notation

Tags: regex, awk

I'm using awk to parse some CIDRs and I need something to match the following addresses:
160.0.0.0/24

but not:
160.0.0.0/24aaa57

So it should match only in case of a valid CIDR notation. Also if I understand correctly awk has no /d and so on.

here's an example:

```
awk '$0 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\// {print $0}' somefile.txt
```

Comment: see: [cidr converter using sed or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742839/cidr-converter-using-sed-or-awk) But that is not using awk!, but says "INVALID MASK1:   24444" when feeding with wrong input...

Comment: Is the input just a list of such addresses, one per line? If not, [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that includes sample input showing addresses in context mid-line, multiple per line, etc. and the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrounging together a list of ip/mask examples from the question and other answers:

```
$ cat ip.txt
172.20.128.1
172.228.202.1/24
172.268.200.2/2444
138.22.2222/1
10.0.0.1/33
10.0.0.1/32
10.0.0/24
160.0.0.0/24aaa57
160.0.0.0/24
160.0.0.0/24e57
199.0.0.0/24/27
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '

function valid(v,a) { return (int(v)==v && v>=a[0] && v<=a[1] ? 1 : 0) }

BEGIN { FS="/"                                     # split input on "/"
        ip[0]=0; ip[1]=255                         # ip tuple range
        sm[0]=0; sm[1]=32                          # subnet mask range
      }
      { print "############", $0
        n=split($1,a,".")                          # split ip on "."
        if (NF>2 || n!=4) next                     # more than 2 "/"-delimited fields or ip tuple count !=4?
        for (i=1;i<=4;i++)                         # loop through ip tuples
            if (! valid(a[i],ip)) next             # validate each tuple
        if (NF==2 && ! valid($2,sm)) next          # validate the subnet mask (if provided)
      }
1                                                  # if we get here we have a valid ip(/mask) so print it
' ip.txt
```

This generates:

```
############ 172.20.128.1
172.20.128.1                            << valid
############ 172.228.202.1/24
172.228.202.1/24                        << valid
############ 172.268.200.2/2444
############ 138.22.2222/1
############ 10.0.0.1/33
############ 10.0.0.1/32
10.0.0.1/32                             << valid
############ 10.0.0/24
############ 160.0.0.0/24aaa57
############ 160.0.0.0/24
160.0.0.0/24                            << valid
############ 160.0.0.0/24e57
############ 199.0.0.0/24/27
```

Answer (score 2):

Valid CIDR doesn't just mean four sets of digits separated by periods.  Valid CIDR requires each number to be between `0` and `255`.  Also, the subnet mask must be between `/0` and `/32`.  Or it could be not present at all, which would imply `/32`.

Per https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html :

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Would be a good regex for satisfying the four dotted octets.  Adding the subnet mask would lead to:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(/(?:3[0-2]|[0-2]?[0-9]))?\b
```

And sample output:

```
sridhar@ganymede:~> cat ip-test.txt 
172.20.128.1
172.228.202.1/24
172.268.200.2/2444
138.22.2222/1
10.0.0.1/33
10.0.0.1/32
10.0.0/24
sridhar@ganymede:~> egrep -o '\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(/(?:3[0-2]|[0-2]?[0-9]))?\b' ip-test.txt 
172.20.128.1
172.228.202.1/24
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.1/32
sridhar@ganymede:~>
```

Comment: `172.268.200.2/2444` and `10.0.0.1/33` are both invalid (bad subnet mask) but they're treated differently: 1st is ignored but 2nd has `/33` dropped and then printed?

Comment: `egrep` has been deprecated in favor of `grep -E` for about 20 years and that regexp contains constructs that are undefined behavior per POSIX, e.g `(?` is a regexp repetition operator `?` with nothing preceding it. Your regexp may work with PCREs, idk, but it won't do what I think you're trying to do with EREs.

Comment: @markp-fuso I'm still working on it a litle.

Answer (score 2):

An awk solution, without regular expressions:

```
awk -F "[./]" '
   function checkip() {
           return $1>=1 && $1<=255 && $2>=0 && $2<=255 && $3>=0 && $3<=255 && $4>=0 && $4<=255 && $5>=8 && $5<=32
   }
   { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,checkip() }
' input.txt
```

This checks on CIDR with the info from [How to Calculate a CIDR](https://matt-rickard.com/how-to-calculate-a-cidr)

Now you only have to make your output after your own needs...

Comment: That would treat `160.0.0.0/24aaa57` the same as `160.0.0.0/24`which the OP said they did not want. You could add a numeric test, e.g. `$1 == $1+0` for each part of the address to ensure it's all just numbers.

Comment: `24aaa57>=8` evaluates to false, will will make `checkip()` return  false. And `84aaa57<=32` also returns false. I think all possibilities are covered.

Comment: see: https://bitbucket.org/awkjs/workspace/snippets/REApnR

Comment: Ah, right, it'd have to be `24e57` or similar instead of `24a57` so it could be interpreted as a number and then `$1 == $1+0` wouldn't help. It'd have to be `$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/` to ensure it's a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

> Also if I understand correctly awk has no /d and so on.

GNU `AWK` features so-called character classes, which are described in [Bracket Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html) chapter of User's Guide and are designed to be used inside `[` and `]`, for example if you need to find lines containing letter followed by digit in `file.txt`, you might express that as

```
awk '/[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]/' file.txt
```

> 160.0.0.0/24 but not: 160.0.0.0/24aaa57

In order to prevent matching part rather than whole word provides `\y` word boundary described in [Regexp operartos](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
24 xyz
24a yz
24ab z
```

then

```
awk '/24\y/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
24 xyz
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

> So it should match only in case of a valid CIDR notation.

Considering that it stipulates each element to be in certain range it might be more straightforward to exploit arithmetic comparison rather than regular expression.